# NullPointerException when trying to get NavController

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-graph

I cannot understand what is the reason for the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`

This is my host fragment:

```
class HostFragment : Fragment() {
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_host, container, false)

        // error here
        val navHostFragment = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.hostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        //

        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        root.host_text_view.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Tag", "clicked")

            navController.navigate(R.id.action_hostFragment_to_secondFragment)
        }

        return root
    }
}
```

I want to navigate to SecondFragment by clicking on the textView. And back.

And nav graph .xml file:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/hostFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
        android:name="com.example.test.HostFragment"
        android:label="fragment_host"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_host" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hostFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.test.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_hostFragment"
            app:destination="@id/hostFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

The Navigation graph has its final form like:
[image]

Comment: `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.hostFragment)` looks for a Fragment on the `android:id="@+id/hostFragment"` in your Activity's layout. Can you include your activity's layout and where you have your `NavHostFragment` added to your layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to use Navigation Graph is after the view is created, since some view takes time to create so u might get this exception as your view is still in processing or creating the view.

so to avoid this , u can use OnViewCreated() as

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    
       view.imgNumbrLookUp.setOnClickListener { 
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_webActivity) 
       }       
}
```

Comment: Navigation offers methods to get the `NavController` directly from the Fragment itself as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate), there's no reason to use the methods that take a view.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEO2X5OU3MY for ref.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find your navHostFragment to navigate

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_host, container, false)

        
        root.host_text_view.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Tag", "clicked")


            if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == hostFragment)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_hostFragment_to_secondFragment)

        }
```

You can check for Kotlin methods to navigate
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate